# To solve a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation

$3 \Big(\dfrac {dy}{dx}\Big)\Big(\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\Big)^2 + \Bigg(\Big(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2 -1\Bigg) \Bigg(\Big(\dfrac {dy}{dx}\Big)^3 -\dfrac{dy}{dx}  -\dfrac{d^3y}{dx^3}\Bigg) =0$   ?

Comment: To whoever might prefer:
$$3y'(y'')^2+\bigl((y')^2-1\bigr)\bigl((y')^3-y'-y'''\bigr)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Put

$$y'=z \implies y''=z' \implies y'''=z'' $$

and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

If $u = y'/\sqrt{(y')^2-1}$, you should get $u'' + u = 0$, so $u = a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$ for constants $a$, $b$.